# What counts as pseudo-replication?

Tags: post-hoc, pseudorepliction

I'm interested in adding a new factor to my data set (to model against my response), but I need help thinking through if doing so would introduce pseudo-replication, or other problems as well.

The way the data was collected entailed throwing 3 nets per location/site and aggregating all catches to a single count per site, season, and year. Counts per site can be a mix of different size classes that were all caught at the same time and place. Therefore, I'm worried if I split the single count value into different size classes it will introduce problems in my model (counts won't be associated with unique site-season-year combinations, there will be duplicates).

This is a post- survey design, data collection, and model selection hypothesis. If that is a separate problem I'd like to learn more about it too. **For context, this is an ecological monitoring project where data is collected on a continual basis at the same sites and generally during the same months, each year.** It seems reasonable that new hypotheses would come up, but I'm not sure what this does to the results/how they should be interpreted. The goal was to model fish counts against time, season, location, and now size class (essentially seeing if fish of different sizes have different annual trends in abundance).

Example code of scenario:

```
count <- c(5,3,2)
size_class <- c(1,2,3)

df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(count, size_class))

df2$year <- 2008
df2$site <- 1
df2$season <- "DRY"

df <- df2[1,]
df[1,1] <- 10
df[1,2] <- NA # I made this 'NA' b/c it wasn't original a factor for consideration
```

Original form of the data (w/ 47 sites, 15 years, 2 seasons, and each row is a count of various species caught)

```
> df
  count size_class year site season
1    10         NA 2008    1    DRY
```

Idea of splitting data to introduce new factor in the model (same hypothetical data, but split into age classes)

```
> df2
  count size_class year site season
1     5          1 2008    1    DRY
2     3          2 2008    1    DRY
3     2          3 2008    1    DRY
```

**What issues would I encounter if I analyzed `df2` instead of `df`? What issues come with re-analyzing data?**

I apologize for this potentially being 2 questions in one...

**EDIT:**

Each row in the data set represents a single count of each species caught in a year-season-site combo., but my model is only on one species. I'm referring to different "class sizes" of that single species (to see if juveniles can be split into smaller sub-groups).